# Cookie name and value into Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, cookies

I'm trying to get all of the domain's cookies and store the name and the value into two separate arrays. Let's say I got the cookies with `document.cookie` and parsed it into an array:

```
["cookie0=value0","cookie1=value1"]
```

How could I extract the name and the values and turn it into two separate arrays? Should be like this:

```
var cookie_names = ["cookie0","cookie1"]
var cookie_values = ["value0","value1"]
```

I've tried to extract them with `.split`, but have no clue how to implement them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try out this function

```
function myFunction () {
    var cookie_names = [];
    var cookie_values = [];
    var cookies = ["cookie0=value0","cookie1=value1"];
    var count = 0;
    for(var i in cookies){
        cookie_names[count] = cookies[i].split("=")[0];
        cookie_values[count] = cookies[i].split("=")[1];
        count++;
    }
    console.log(cookie_names);
    console.log(cookie_values);

}
```

But you have to make sure that `cookies` array should be in the proper format so that it can be splitted by `=`. In my opinion, it would be much easier of you can make the cookies array an JS Object.

eg: `var cookies = {"cookie0" : "value0", "cookie1" : "value1"}`

In which case you can change the for loop into this

```
for(var i in cookies){
      cookie_names[count] = i;
      cookie_values[count] = cookies[i];
      count++;
}
```

Comment: Adding a function is a bit unnecessary, other than that it works, thanks. Kudos for the JS Object tip! :)

Comment: Yep I see ;) glad to help!